# Autocomplete css classes in Chrome DevTools like in FF Developer Edition

Tags: autocomplete, google-chrome-devtools, developer-tools

I've searched the Net for hours and days and I couldn't find the answer to a simple question:

Is this possible, to use CSS classes autocomplete in Chrome DevTools but in the way that Firefox Developer Edition does it? I mean that FF css editor takes classes from currently edited CSS file AND inspected HTML document and add it to autocomplete lists.

In Chrome DevTools editor takes only classes that has been already used. Is there any way or plugin to apply FF autocomplete to Chrome?

Thank you

Comment: are we talking about editing rule selectors in the styles panel, or about editing CSS file in the sources panel?

Comment: @AndreyLushnikov: I was talking about CSS editing in sources panel. This is so handy in FF, but for couple other reasons I'd rather use chrome devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not available. You can file a feature request in the [chromium issue tracker](https://crbug.com) to let the team know it is something you want.

Comment: I filed an issue in case people want this in chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=611749