# Autocompletion for adding a new class to an element in Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: firefox-developer-tools

I'm not getting any autocompletion / "intellisense" for the CSS classes in the *Add new class* field in Firefox Developer Tools (.cls button).

Does this field even support autocompletion? Is there some setup that needs to be done to get it working? 
I'm unable to find any documentation, threads or requests about this.

[image: Firefox Inspector Add new class]
<sup>*Firefox Inspector Add new class*</sup>

[image: Chrome Inspector Add new class]
<sup>*Chrome Inspector Add new class*</sup>

*Firefox 62.0 64bit*

Comment: Could you link to that "Autocompletion for Chrome like Firefox" thread? I guess it's an autocompletion in some other place, but want to read that thread.

Comment: @SebastianZartner Sorry, I now noticed that I might have misinterpret the topic of that thread, I'm still unsure what the thread is about.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694362/autocomplete-css-classes-in-chrome-devtools-like-in-ff-developer-edition

Comment: Thank you for the link! Like you, the person who asked the question clarified it in a comment. He or she referred to the *Sources* panel, in which you can edit the style sheets. This is called *Style Editor* in Firefox, therefore something different than the *Rules* side panel. Btw. I've edited your question to link to that other thread and clarified the title a bit. So it's easier to spot what you refer to.

Comment: @SebastianZartner Maybe remove that sentence entirely since it's not relevant due to my misinterpretation? Thank you for taking care of this request at Bugzilla, now I can just sit back, relax and follow the development ;)

Comment: You're right, the sentence is obsolete, so feel free to remove the sentence. The head of the DevTools team already commented, so that's a good sign. :-) But I don't want to set the expectations too high, as I don't know their priorities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firefox DevTools have autocompletions in many different places, though as far as I know, there is no autocompletion for class names when adding a new class to an element.

Therefore I have created an enhancement request now:
https://bugzil.la/1492797

Update:

This feature is now implemented in Firefox 80.

Comment: If you follow the link in my answer, you can see that someone already provided a patch a month ago, though it is not fixed yet. For further info, I suggest you follow the enhancement request.

Comment: The patch got accepted and the changes will be in Firefox 80.